# redux-form dynamic name does not change the reducer name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using a redux-form like this:

```
 <RenderForm
      form={form.name}
      elements={form.elements}
      initialValues={form.initialValues}
      method={form.method}
      target={form.target}
      validate={parseValidations(form.elements)}
      enableReinitialize
      keepDirtyOnReinitialize
      {...props}
    />
```

and

```
const RenderForm = reduxForm()(Form);
```

and

```
const Form = ({ children, method, target, form, elements, msg, handleSubmit, onChange }) => (
  <form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    id={form && `form-${form}`}
    method={method}
    action={target}
    onChange={onChange}
  >
    { msg ? <IconTooltip
      id={`info-${form.name}`}
      content={msg.p}
      title={msg.h}
      top={30}
      showStart
      showMedium
    /> : null}
    <div>
      {formFactory(elements.filter(e => !e.noBackground))}
    </div>
    <div>
      {formFactory(elements.filter(e => e.noBackground))}
    </div>
    {children}
  </form>
);
```

Now my problem is - when the name of the form changes it won't change the reducer in redux.

E.g. I have a wizard and form named category in step 1 of wizard -> now i change to step 2 of the wizard and there is a form called amount. It will always stay category.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation on how to build wizard forms over here http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/wizard/?

The documentation mentions that if you want to build a wizard, you need to connect each page of the wizard to the same form name, so you'd need to specify that explicitly.

Perhaps that solves your issue?

Comment: Hmm interesting - actually i don't need to change the name so I will try that.